# PHP Regex or DOMDocument for Matching & Removing URLs?

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I'm trying to extract links from html page using DOM:

```
$html = file_get_contents('links.html');
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$a = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($a as $link){
    //echo out the href attribute of the <A> tag.
    echo $link->getAttribute('href').'<br/>';
}
```

Output:

```
http://dontwantthisdomain.com/dont-want-this-domain-name/
http://dontwantthisdomain2.com/also-dont-want-any-pages-from-this-domain/
http://dontwantthisdomain3.com/dont-want-any-pages-from-this-domain/
http://domain1.com/page-X-on-domain-com.html

http://dontwantthisdomain.com/dont-want-link-from-this-domain-name.html
http://dontwantthisdomain2.com/dont-want-any-pages-from-this-domain/
http://domain.com/page-XZ-on-domain-com.html

http://dontwantthisdomain.com/another-page-from-same-domain-that-i-dont-want-to-be-included/
http://dontwantthisdomain2.com/same-as-above/
http://domain3.com/page-XYZ-on-domain3-com.html
```

I would like to remove all results matching dontwantthisdomain.com, dontwantthisdomain2.com and dontwantthisdomain3.com so the output will looks like that:

```
http://domain1.com/page-X-on-domain-com.html
http://domain.com/page-XZ-on-domain-com.html
http://domain3.com/page-XYZ-on-domain3-com.html
```

Some people saying I should not use regex for html and others that it's ok. Could somebody point the best way how I can remove unwanted urls from my html file? :)

Comment: Well the remaining output of your script is no HTML any more, is it? So it's perfectly fine to filter by regular expression once you have scraped the links from the HTML with a DOM parser. Although in this case, there are probably simpler alternatives. For instance, you could obtain the domain (*host*) using [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and then simply check whether it's in a blacklist of unwanted domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None regex solution (without potential errors :-) :

```
$html='
http://dontwantthisdomain.com/dont-want-this-domain-name/
http://dontwantthisdomain2.com/also-dont-want-any-pages-from-this-domain/
http://dontwantthisdomain3.com/dont-want-any-pages-from-this-domain/
http://domain1.com/page-X-on-domain-com.html

http://dontwantthisdomain.com/dont-want-link-from-this-domain-name.html
http://dontwantthisdomain2.com/dont-want-any-pages-from-this-domain/
http://domain.com/page-XZ-on-domain-com.html

http://dontwantthisdomain.com/another-page-from-same-domain-that-i-dont-want-to-be-included/
http://dontwantthisdomain2.com/same-as-above/
http://domain3.com/page-XYZ-on-domain3-com.html
';

$html=explode("\n", $html);
$dontWant=array('dontwantthisdomain.com','dontwantthisdomain2.com','dontwantthisdomain3.com');
foreach ($html as $link) {
    $ok=true;
    foreach($dontWant as $notWanted) {
        if (strpos($link, $notWanted)>0) { 
            $ok=false;
        }
        if (trim($link=='')) $ok=false;
    }
    if ($ok) $final_result[]=$link;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($final_result);
echo '</pre>';
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://domain1.com/page-X-on-domain-com.html
    [1] => http://domain.com/page-XZ-on-domain-com.html
    [2] => http://domain3.com/page-XYZ-on-domain3-com.html
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
function extract_domains($buffer, $whitelist) {
    preg_match_all("#<a\s+.*?href=\"(.+?)\".*?>(.+?)</a>#i", $buffer, $matches);
    $result = array();
    foreach($matches[1] as $url) {
        $url = urldecode($url);
        $parts = @parse_url((string) $url);
        if ($parts !== false && in_array($parts['host'], $whitelist)) {
            $result[] = $parts['host'];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$domains = extract_domains(file_get_contents("/path/to/html.htm"), array('stackoverflow.com', 'google.com', 'sub.example.com')));
```

It does a rough match on the all the `<a>` with `href=`, grabs what's between the quotes, then filters it based on your whitelist of domains.

Comment: Why `@parse_url`? Just asking. Suppressing errors is not a good idea.

Comment: If `parse_url()` fails, it will produce a warning (or at least a notice). As the data is what I would consider "user input", there is no telling what kind of trickery will be placed in the `href=""` attribute. I suppressed the error then manually checked it with the strict not equals in the `if-statement` right below it.